# StackView of images in CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cashapelayer

I am trying to build a somewhat circular path of images (similar to the image posted below). I not sure how to approach this, my initial thought is using a CAShapeLayer to draw the circular part, but not sure how to do this with images. Is there a more simple approach to implement this for an oval?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way is to use a little trig. Basically, we'll make a large circle for reference purposes, and place a number of smaller circles on its circumference, equally spaced, between a given start and end angle that we choose so they fan out as we like.

Here's something to get you started:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let c = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
        let radius = c.bounds.width/2
        c.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        c.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        self.view.addSubview(c)
        c.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
        
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 50
        let endAngle = 180 - startAngle
        
        let n = 6
        let delta = (endAngle-startAngle)/CGFloat(n-1)
        var degrees: CGFloat = startAngle
        degrees -= delta
        
        for _ in 0..<n {
            degrees += delta
            
            let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
            v.layer.cornerRadius = v.bounds.width/2
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            c.addSubview(v)
            v.center = CGPoint(x: c.bounds.midX, y: c.bounds.midY)
            v.center.y -= radius*cos(degrees*CGFloat.pi/180)
            v.center.x += radius*sin(degrees*CGFloat.pi/180)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want a more oval shape, you can use a larger reference circle and adjust the angle range to be more narrow. And add this code to position the reference circle:

```
let d = radius - self.view.bounds.width
let padding: CGFloat = 50
if d > 0 {
    c.frame.origin.x -= d+padding
}
```

Like so:

[image]

And here's your design alpha'd with the above 2 images to show the difference in curves. The first and last circles are all in the same spot for each image, but the curve path varies. Your design has a curve path in between those two, so with the right reference circle size you can have a curve path that's almost exact.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, the only issue is I am using an oval

Comment: You could use a larger reference circle to get almost any oval you want. It won't be exactly the curve of your initial design but you can get it pretty darn close. Plus, if you ever want to scroll that stack view, it's as easy as rotating the reference circle.